# php variable not found in other php block

Tags: php

After migrate a webpage to a new server (with more updated php-server), I have problems in some pages. These pages uses some different php blocks:

```
<?
$result = 1;
?>
some html code...
<?php
$result2 = $result;
?>
```

This works before the migration, but now the $result in the second part is reported as undefined variable in the apache2 error log.

How can I make that variables still are defined in second part?

Comment: First try using `<?php` and not `<?` in the first section as your new environment may have `short-tags` turned off. _Its always best to use the long tag method for this reason_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to use long tags for php: `<?` needs to be: `<?php`

Either that, or enable `short_open_tag` in php.ini

Comment: Surely this would be adequately described in a comment